# Adding values to array from multiple curl requests

Tags: php, arrays, curl, curl-multi

I am currently using [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) and I am trying to create an array of urls from JSON responses that match the error code in my code below. My latest try was using array_push which resulted in the urls creating an array of the same urls like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com
    [1] => http://example.com
)
```

And what I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com
    [1] => http://example2.com
    [2] => http://example3.com
    [3] => http://example4.com

)
```

My code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Curl\MultiCurl;

$curl_opts = [
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=> true
];

$out = array();
$errors = array();
$multi_curl = new MultiCurl();

$multi_curl->success(function ($instance) use (&$con, $out, $errors) {
    $out[$instance->out] = $instance->response;

   foreach ($out as $output){
        $error = $output->error;
        $p_id = $output->p_id;

    if (isset($error) && $error == '2'){
        echo '2 error';
        $errors[] = $instance->url;
        array_push($errors, $instance->url);
    }
}
    print_r($errors);
});

foreach($curl_opts as $key=>$value)
    $multi_curl->setOpt($key, $value);

$multi_curl->complete(function($instance){
    echo 1;
});

$multi_curl->addGet('http://example.com');
$multi_curl->addGet('http://example2.com');
$multi_curl->addGet('http://example3.com');
$multi_curl->addGet('http://example4.com');

$multi_curl->setConcurrency(3);
$multi_curl->start();

var_dump($multi_curl);
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Doing both `$errors[] = $instance->url;` and `array_push($errors, $instance->url);` might be why you are seeing two of that url. Comment one of those out, and see how it goes.

Comment: Doing that resets the array it seems and print_r() only shows 1 url after each pass.

Comment: It must be how you are `use`ing the `$errors` global, it may be treating it as a new variable for every `success`, thus it does not increase. As `array_push` and `$array[]=` are basically the same thing. I'm assuming if you moved `print_r($errors);` to after `$multi_curl->start();`, it will be empty.

Comment: It's just weird because the array is aware of how many values there are. For example if I run 4 links then print_r() will show 4 links but it's always 4 of the last link that was passed. You are correc though, moving the print after the start shows nothing.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway.

Comment: That doesn't work because the error value I am looking for is actually a value in the JSON itself that I am looking for. If present, depending on the error number shows different values and I am trying to filter out any error values that equal 2.

Comment: Yup. Ok. Seems to boil down to updating that global, without resorting to `global $errors;`. Sorry I wasn't of more help!

Comment: It's fine, I appreciate your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have had the same issue in the past using RollingCurl. I forgot to add & at the beginning of the arrays in the success function.
Instead of this:

```
$multi_curl->success(function ($instance) use (&$con, $out, $errors)
```

It should have been this:

```
$multi_curl->success(function ($instance) use (&$con, &$out, &$errors)
```

If you want to access values outside of the loop you must define `&` before your variable like I just showed. I do not know of another way, if someone knows something better I'd be happy to hear it.